# Iterate over std::vector containing concurrent_queue<string>* and print the strings

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++, vector

I am trying to debug a multithreaded system, to do that i need to log the content of a vector for an extended period (1 hour).
I want to print all the strings contained in `vector<concurrent_queue<MyObject>*> myContainer`, I have tried the following:

```
for (auto q : myContainer)
    for(concurrent_queue<MyObject>::iterator i = q->unsafe_begin(); i != q->unsafe_end(); ++i)
        cout << i->toString()<<endl;
```

But i get a debug assertion after few runs in `Visual Studio` in :

`msvcp110d.dll!Concurrency::details::_Concurrent_queue_iterator_rep::choose(unsigned __int64 k) Line 339    C++`

I am thinking it's caused by access violation caused by a race condition.

How can i properly iterate over such structure without issues ?

Comment: Concurrent queue is only thread safe in regards to push and pop. Iterating it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, and to properly iterate it you need a  synchronized access.

Comment: You can't do that this way - unsafe_begin and unsafe_end are named unsafe for a reason, they only work if the queue isn't being changed while they are accessing it. If the order does not matter, you can pop all the elements out of the queue, print them, and push them back in. Instead of that I'd recommend that you do the printing wherever you are pushing and popping the content.